# Using ng-model on two inputs, same value

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to use ng-model on input that receive a value of an other input ...

My code doesn't work and I don't understand why, is that possible to set ng-model to an input with Angular values?

My code

```js
var BottomApp = angular.module('BottomApp', []);

BottomApp.controller('SeoArticle', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.seoTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
  $scope.createSeoUrl = function(string){
    var string;
    string = string.replace(/'+/g, '');
    string = string.replace(/"+/g, '');
    return string.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  };
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="SeoArticle">
<input type="text" id="title" name="article[title]" class="form-control" placeholder="title" ng-model="seoTitle">

<input type="text" name="article[seo_title]" value="{{seoTitle2}}">
<input type="text" name="article[seo_url]" value="{{seoUrl2}}">

<div class="ui-block-title"><h5>{{seoTitle}}</h5></div>

<input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" value="{{seoTitle}}" ng-model="seoTitle2">
<input type="text" id="seo_url" class="form-control" placeholder="seo_url" value="{{createSeoUrl(seoTitle)}}" ng-model="seoUrl2">

<div class="panel">
  <div class="seo-overview">
    <p class="seo-overview-title">{{seoTitle}}</p>
    <p class="seo-overview-url">{{createSeoUrl(seoTitle)}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

:

Comment: I'd suggest building a trivial sample for the question that illustrates just the concept that you are asking about.

Comment: Firs thing I noticed is that createSeoUrl has a parameter called 'string' and there is a variable called 'string' declared inside it.

Comment: Yes I changed it but that's not the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YHUyAN4qeiqB7kZUAlOH?p=preview).

I have added the ng-app call to the body tag

```
<body ng-app="BottomApp">
```

and removed the string variable declaration from createSeoUrl.

Edit: I don't think you can do it within the DOM. You should use a watcher. See the updated Plunker.

```
$scope.$watch("seoTitle", function(newValue) {
    $scope.seoTitle2 = newValue;
    $scope.seoUrl2 = $scope.createSeoUrl(newValue);
})

<input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" ng-model="seoTitle2">
<input type="text" id="seo_url" class="form-control" placeholder="seo_url" ng-model="seoUrl2">
```

Comment: Doesn't work, my inputs `name="article[seo_title]` and `name="article[seo_url]` have to be filled...

Comment: the value of the input with `ng-model="seoTitle2"` should be the value of the input with `ng-model="seoTitle"` and the value of the input with `name="article[seo_title]"` should be the value of the input with `ng-model="seoTitle2"`...